# UsernameNotFoundException caught while trying how user sign-in works by sending POST request through POSTMAN

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I got UsernameNotFoundException when i try to check how user sign-in works by sending POST request through POSTMAN with

> `url-"http://localhost:8080/users/login"`

Username is present in database but still i am getting this exception.
So please help me out!!

### GitHub code-https://github.com/PrateekChauhan04/mobileapp

```
## Console ##
2020-01-02 21:56:28.618 ERROR 14648 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: prateek5fb@gmail.com
    at com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.getUser(UserServiceImpl.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.security.AuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_231]
```

```
## UserServiceImpl ##

    package com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.service.impl;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.io.entity.UserEntity;
    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.io.repositories.UserRepository;
    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.service.UserService;
    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.shared.Utils;
    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.shared.dto.UserDto;



    @Service
    public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    Utils utils;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


    @Override
    public UserDto createUser(UserDto user) {
        if (userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Record already present");

        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, userEntity);

        String publicUserId = utils.generateUserId(30);
        userEntity.setUserId(publicUserId);
        userEntity.setEncryptedPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        UserEntity storedUserDetails = userRepository.save(userEntity);

        UserDto returnValue = new UserDto();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(storedUserDetails, returnValue);

        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDto getUser(String email) {
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (userEntity != null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);
        UserDto returnValue = new UserDto();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userEntity, returnValue);
        return returnValue;

    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (userEntity == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);

         return new User(userEntity.getEmail(),userEntity.getEncryptedPassword(),new ArrayList<>());

    }   


    @Override
    public UserDto getUserByUserId(String userId) {
        UserDto returnValue = new UserDto();
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUserId(userId);
        if (userEntity == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userId);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userEntity, returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    }
```

```
## UserEntity ##


    package com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.io.entity;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;


    @Entity(name = "users")
    public class UserEntity implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3772691377276902875L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String userId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 120,unique=true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String encryptedPassword;

    private String emailVerificationToken;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean emailVerificationStatus=false;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEncryptedPassword() {
        return encryptedPassword;
    }

    public void setEncryptedPassword(String encryptedPassword) {
        this.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
    }

    public String getEmailVerificationToken() {
        return emailVerificationToken; 
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationToken(String emailVerificationToken) {
        this.emailVerificationToken = emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public Boolean getEmailVerificationStatus() {
        return emailVerificationStatus;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationStatus(Boolean emailVerificationStatus) {
        this.emailVerificationStatus = emailVerificationStatus;
    }



    }
```

```
## UserRepository##

    package com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.io.repositories;

    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.io.entity.UserEntity;


    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity,Long> {

    UserEntity findByEmail(String email);
    UserEntity findByUserId(String userId);
    }
```

```
## UserController ##

    package com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.ui.controller;

    import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.service.UserService;
    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.shared.dto.UserDto;
    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.ui.model.request.UserDetailsRequestModel;
    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.ui.model.response.UserRest;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("users") // http://localhost:8080/users

    public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public UserRest getUser(@PathVariable String id) {
        UserRest returnValue = new UserRest();
        UserDto userDto=userService.getUserByUserId(id);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDto, returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public UserRest createUser(@RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails) {
        UserRest returnValue = new UserRest();
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userDetails, userDto);

        UserDto createdUser = userService.createUser(userDto);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(createdUser, returnValue);

        return returnValue;
    }

    @PutMapping
    public String updateUser() {
        return "Update user was called";
    }

    @DeleteMapping
    public String deleteUser() {
        return "Delete user was called";
    }
    }
```

```
## AuthenticationFilter ##

    package com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.security;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;

    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
    import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.SpringApplicationContext;
    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.service.UserService;
    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.shared.dto.UserDto;
    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.ui.model.request.UserLoginRequestModel;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

    import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
    import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;


    public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {


        private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        }

        @Override
        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                throws AuthenticationException {
            try {
                UserLoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(),
                        UserLoginRequestModel.class);

                return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getEmail(), creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
                Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
            String userName = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
            // String tokenSecret =new SecurityConstants().getTokenSecret();

            String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(userName)
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.getTokenSecret()).compact();

             UserService userService = (UserService)SpringApplicationContext.getBean("userServiceImpl");
            UserDto userDto=userService.getUser(userName);
            res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
            res.addHeader("userId",userDto.getUserId());
        }
    }
```

```
## WebSecurity ##

        package com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.security;

    import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

    import com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.service.UserService;


    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{


        private final  UserService userDetailsService;
        private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

        public WebSecurity(UserService userDetailsService,BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
            this.userDetailsService=userDetailsService;
            this.bCryptPasswordEncoder=bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
            .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

        }
        public AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter()throws Exception{
            final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
            filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/users/login");
            return filter;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are throwing UsernameNotFoundException when you actually found the user in UserServiceImpl.getUser().

```java
if (userEntity != null)
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);
```

Comment: It happens to us all.